# Changing leftBarButtonItem with flip transition?

Tags: iphone, transition

In my code I programmatically change leftBarButtonItem with a UIButton to a UIActivityIndicatorView, I would like to know how to perform a flip transition when changing, any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm.. I have a feeling that to do a flip transition, you need to have a UIView.

So.. you could make a custom barButtonItem and add to it a flipView:

```
UIView *flipView = [[UIView alloc] init....];
BarButtonItem *barbutton = [[BarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:flipView];
```

then add your original view to the flipView, this can contain whatever you like...

```
[flipView addSubview:<original view>];
```

Then to flip this into a UIActivityIndicatorView, I think you need to do something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flip" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:flipView cache:YES];

[<original view> removeFromSuperView];
[flipView addSubview:<activityIndicatorView>];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You'll probably have to keep a reference to your flipView somewhere so you can bring back a reference to it when you want to perform the flip.

Hope this helps!

Nick.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Elements sample.  They are doing a flip in a toolbar there.