# UIBarButtonItem with custom view but also having a UIBarButtonItemStyle

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I am creating a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view in order to achieve a transition to a `UIActivityIndicatorView` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614988/changing-leftbarbuttonitem-with-flip-transition).

However I really want my button to retain a normal `UIBarButtonItemStyle` such as `UIBarButtonitemStyleBordered`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want to have something like the Locate button in Maps.app, where it shows the target icon and changes into an activity indicator whiile it's locating the device?

Unfortunately UIBarButtonItems created with `-initWithImage:style:target:action:` or `-initWithTitle:style:target:action:` don't support arbitrary views inside the button.

You'll probably have to draw the button border yourself.  You could use an image for that, and achieve the effect by stacking a UIActivityIndicatorView on top of a UIImageView containing an image of a button border.